# Migrating clap-rs from 3-beta to 3-stable: `error: no method named `about` found for struct `Arg` in the current scope`

Tags: rust, clap

So I'm reading the docs and I can see the attribute still exists https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/v3.1.6/examples/derive_ref/README.md#arg-attributes

I'm getting:

`` no method named `about` found for struct `Arg` in the current scope ``

Am I missing something?

```
#[derive(Parser)]
#[clap(about("Entry point"))]
struct ForecastingCli {
    #[clap(
        short('c'),
        long,
        global(true),
        value_name("FILE"),
        about = "config file"
    )]
    config: Option<PathBuf>,
}
```

Comment: I can't find an `about`-attribute for `Arg` in your link. There is only an `about`-attribute for commands and not for args. I think you try to create a help of the `Arg` which can be done with the `help`-attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in `3.*.beta` [`help()`](https://docs.rs/clap/3.0.0-beta.5/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.help) was deprecated in favor of `about()`, because they were looked as redundant, and somewhat similar to `App::about()`.

But then they changed their minds and [reverted](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/commit/7e899cd340c01b13388e7bb3649f4252924ad21f) that change before the `3.0` release, deleting instead `about()`.

So, just use [`Arg::help()`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.help) instead.

Same thing for `long_help()` and `long_about()`.